# GuzzleHttp Can't Be Installed On Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I wanted to install GuzzleHttp package.

Firstly I tried running `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`, but I got this error:

```
Problem 1
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.4.0, ..., 7.4.x-dev] require guzzlehttp/promises ^1.5 -> found guzzlehttp/promises[dev-master, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.x-dev (alias of dev-master)] but the package is fixed to 1.4.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.4 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.4.0, ..., 7.4.x-dev].
```

Then I tried to install a downgraded version so I run this:

```
composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle:~5.3"
```

But got this error:

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~5.3, found guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.0, ..., 5.3.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - anhskohbo/no-captcha is locked to version 3.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - anhskohbo/no-captcha 3.3.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.2|^7.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[dev-master, 6.2.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev, 7.0.0-beta.1, ..., 7.4.x-dev (alias of dev-master)] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~5.3).

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

So what's going wrong here? How can I properly install GuzzleHttp for Laravel 5.8 version?

Comment: `anhskohbo/no-captcha` already requires Guzzle (`"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2|^7.0"`), should already be installed

Comment: You should never rely on a dependency including a package you're using in your own application. If that dependency ever changes and stops using said package, then your application will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `-w` flag to you command:

`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle -w`

One of you other dependencies has requiredment `guzzlehttp/promises` which is currently locked to `1.4.1` in your `composer.lock`

The `-w` flag tells composer that it's okay to update dependencies when installing the new dependency.

If that doesn't work then you can try with the `-W` flag instead.